Flutter Data Table Not Clearing Previously Typed In Cells When Switching Filter
I am currently developing an app with Flutter. I am having an issue with the data table. The way my table works is that the user can filter between different table types with a drop down button. So for example say the user is on filter one and types in data into the first tile on filter 1. Whenever the user switches to the filter 2 table, the first tile in filter 2 will still have the value that the user just inserted into filter 1. If I don’t insert anything into the table each filter pulls up the previously saved inputs perfectly fine.
I have been trying to find a way to clear out the data in the tiles whenever it switches filters, but I have had no luck.
